# Can devices without Compass/Magnetic sensor support AR?

Tags: android, augmented-reality

I was trying out the sample Android augmented reality app found [here](https://github.com/raweng/augmented-reality-view). 
 It works fine on devices with a magnetic sensor. But it doesn't work in devices with only Accelerometer, which does not have a  Compass/ Magnetometer sensor.

I debugged the code and what I can see is only devices with magnetic sensor gives proper values as the device rotates. Devices with only Accelerometer does not calculate values like `azimuth` 
 and therefore it does not respond to the device rotation and movement.

So since I don't have much knowledge about AR implementation, I just wanted to ask a simple question.
 Can AR be implemented only in devices with `Compass/ Magnetometer`?

devices with only Accelerometer sensor will not support AR in Android?

Comment: I would say that location based AR(like the one in your link) without a compass is not possible as you can not know in what direction you are looking at which means that you can not place an augmentation at the correct position.

Answer (score 0):

Augmented Reality can be implemented in different types.

1. Marker-Based AR (Recognition based AR)
2. QR Based AR
3. Location Based AR
4. Projection Based AR

The example which you checked is under location Based AR.
For Location Based AR App uses

1. the camera view
2. the user’s location
3. and other device sensors, especially a compass (accelerometer and gyroscope can also be useful)

For more example try using Vuforia Sdk you will get more information on Vuforia Developer Site.

Comment: _**especially a compass (accelerometer and gyroscope can also be useful)**_ which means, without also it can be done? compass sensor is not mandatory?

Comment: I have not tried without compass device but if it is Marker-Based AR it should work .